# New objects "attached" to each other

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

just started using bleder two weeks ago, I did a few tutorials and it went OK.

today I started a new one, but when I tried to add a primitive it kind of related to my first object. it doesn't have an independent name (all of them named 'plan' in the panel) and I can't select\edit[image] only one of them. How can I fix this?

Comment: You didn't properly create different objects, you created different meshes into the same objects. You need to get out of Edit mode and get into Object mode if you want to create new objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them in *Object Mode* not in *Edit Mode*. You can also select the vertices of one of the objects in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>P</kbd>, to make a new object from the selection.

[image]
[image]